# What technology to use for an Interactive web map?

Tags: web-mapping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Comparison of JavaScript mapping libraries?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8032/comparison-of-javascript-mapping-libraries)

I need to build a custom interactive web map of my country with all it's regions (Peru). Which tool or technology would be the best way to go?

The idea is to have a map that shows the population of each region with a color scale: the more people the region has, the darker it's painted. Also I need to display some information as text and pictures when I click each region as the maps zooms in.

I've seen around and there are lots of "pre-developed" tools that can be customized but I need to build my own. Flash is already discarded. I was thinking of Java applet but is just an idea.

**System requirements: Apache+PHP+MySQL**

Comment: What are your requirements and available software/databases?

Comment: Are you asking anything that differs from [this thread](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8113/steps-to-start-web-mapping)?

Comment: @blah238 Apache+PHP+MySQL

Answer (score 3):

[Open Layers](http://openlayers.org/) is very popular and flexible. You may want to start there. Many of the other packages available build on OpenLayers.