# Which web application framework is easiest for building website displaying lot of geospatial data?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, web-mapping, boundless-suite

I am building a simple website that displays a lot of geospatial data (which is routed through Geoserver). I was trying to use Drupal-6 to build the website component (non geospatial descriptions) but had plenty of issues dealing with openlayers and other modules as well as deploying it properly.

My goals are simple - to display geospatial data (with Google maps background) and a normal website with a big menu and different explanatory content.

Which web application framework is easiest (for a non web programmer) to achieve these two goals based on your experience

Comment: Kind of difficult to answer. Web application frameworks are for web programmers, so for a non web programmer, it is a bit difficult to say. Did you deploy Drupal yourself (and thus know how to tinker with apache or nginx configuration files)? Or did you just use a pre-installed instance? If you want to use drupal, I would just stick to editing the HTML directly and adding the maps manually using the js API. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/

Comment: I will look into this

Answer (score 2):

first of all i want to advice you to look at [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8032/comparison-of-javascript-mapping-libraries) which has Comparasion of Javascript Mapping Libraries. At least it will give some information about web mapping libraries.

i want to advice as everyone does, openlayers is so good library but it is a bit harder from others because of having good amount of functionality.if you think the way forward openlayers fits like a glove in that web mapping world. Beside this you can take lots of help when you dont solve any problem.

you still want something simple, i advice you [Polymaps](http://polymaps.org/).. it is really so easy to develop a web mapping application.

[image]

> Polymaps is a free JavaScript library for making dynamic, interactive
>   maps in modern web browsers.

i hope it helps you...