# What are the top best webmapping API clients?

Tags: openlayers-2, web-mapping, api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comparison of JavaScript mapping libraries?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8032/comparison-of-javascript-mapping-libraries)

I am looking for the top APIs that I can use to display maps from a number of map servers/sources. (like openlayers and openfscales)
I already know OpenSlales and Openlayers. So are there any other popular APIs for other languages (C++,Java,... ) ?

Answer (score 1):

In the JavaScript arena there is also [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ESRI suit then ArcGIS Java script API is ideal for you.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/index.html