# Mapping API's which one to use

Tags: api, mapping

I am currently doing a project where I want to use some form of mapping API (Google maps or an open source alternative) that can show the location of simulated wind turbines across Ireland. I am trying to understand what would be the most efficient protocol i could use to display information stored in a monitoring database onto the map as quickly as possible.

Comment: Jumping straight to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8032/how-do-various-javascript-mapping-libraries-compare may also be useful